# Entry point was not found mv3 and sharp architecture

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, fluent-nhibernate, s#arp-architecture

Hi i receive this error

Sharp architecture 2.0 works on mvc 3 the error is

> Entry point was not found

I have both mvc 3 and mvc 4 installed on my Pc,as i un-install mvc 4 projects Work Correctly,but is there any one other way that can work i have tried to change assembly settings as well in web.config

Here is the Stack trace

> [EntryPointNotFoundException: Entry point was not found.]
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcRouteHandler.GetSessionStateBehavior(RequestContext
>   requestContext) +159
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcRouteHandler.GetHttpHandler(RequestContext
>   requestContext) +41
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcRouteHandler.System.Web.Routing.IRouteHandler.GetHttpHandler(RequestContext
>   requestContext) +10
>   System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.PostResolveRequestCache(HttpContextBase
>   context) +9024264
>   System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.OnApplicationPostResolveRequestCache(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) +86
>   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +148    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75

Comment: I think that's a regasm issue

Comment: I have MVC4 installed and could not reproduce the problem :S First thing I would try is add an assembly binding in web.config from mvc 1-4 to go to mvc3. Is there a stack trace? maybe it will give us more detail about the problem.

Comment: [As Refrence to This Thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508966/xval-and-asp-net-mvc-2-addmodelstateerrors-problem) , i tried to change assembly but its not working still get the same error of entry point not found

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks , Resolved had to remove all Previous refrences of mvc3   and re-refrence it again from /ProgramFiles/ASP.NET MVC 3/System.Web.Mvc.dll as on default it shows assemblies of only mvc4

Comment: migrated my solution to vs2012 and automagically the System.Web.Mvc.dll from MVC 4 was referenced. Revert those references did the job for me.

Answer (score 3):

There is another way to resolve the "Entry point not found exception", you can add the following  section in your

```
<runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
```

This will instruct the runtime to use MVC4 binaries. We are using this in our projects without any exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error message and it was caused by the fact that I used nuget to get version `5.0.0.0` of `System.Web.Mvc`. I rolled back to an earlier version via package manager console like so: `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 4.0.30506` and that solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, in Visual Studio you can fix this error with the Package Manager Console and the command:

```
update-package
```